# QT 5.13.2 C++ issue Member access into incomplete type 'Ui::UsersWidget'

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

My aim is creating a widget that will display users table info, so in future I can include this widget into mainwindow layout.

I'm creating a class named `UsersWidget` inherited from `QWidget` and getting error in `userswidget.h` file:

```
userswidget.h:21:21: error: field has incomplete type 'Ui::UsersWidget'
userswidget.h:8:7: note: forward declaration of 'Ui::UsersWidget'
```

**Code:**

.pro file

```
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    userswidget.cpp

HEADERS += \
    init_db.h \
    mainwindow.h \
    userswidget.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui \
    userswidget.ui
```

userswidget.cpp

```
#include "userswidget.h"

UsersWidget::UsersWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

userswidget.h

```
#ifndef USERSWIDGET_H
#define USERSWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "ui_userswidget.h" // ???

namespace Ui{
class UsersWidget;
}

class UsersWidget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit UsersWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:

public slots:

private:
    Ui::UsersWidget ui; // issue: field has incomplete type 'Ui::UsersWidget'
};

#endif // USERSWIDGET_H
```

To my mind this is due to the auto-generated "ui_userswidget.h" file, but I cannot figure it out myself.

Comment: `ui` should be a pointer.

Comment: Also, you can generally just include the ui header file; and have `UsersWidget` extend from `Ui::UsersWidget`. The auto-generated ui header has the full class definition, and therefore doesn't need a forward declaration.

Comment: Just made ```ui``` a pointer.
Now im getting this error: ```member access into incomplete type 'Ui::UsersWidget'```  in ```userswidget.cpp``` ```ui->setupUi(this);```

Comment: You still need the full class definition before you use it.

Comment: So how can I actually achive it?

Comment: By including the header with the definition in the cpp file? Presumably that would be `ui_userswidget.h`

Comment: So im adding ```#include "ui_userswidget.h"``` in ```userswidget.cpp``` and getting same error :(

Comment: What is in `ui_userswidget.h`?

Comment: ```ui_userswidget.h```
https://pastebin.com/pCe2YAN3

Comment: Ah, okay, I see the issue now. You named the object Form, not UsersWidget. You need to change the objects name, in Qtcreator presumably, then regenerate the moc files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `ui` should be a pointer

2) Name the ui object "UsersWidget", not "Form"